# Как вызвать диалоговое окно и указать путь к файлу?

Tags: c#, wpf

В данный момент для прочитывания файла используется StremReader.

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\\ROGIB.CSV"))
{

}
```

Помогите сделать так, чтобы открывалось диалоговое окно и я сам мог выбрать какой мне файл открыть.

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](https://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/UI_WPF/level23/23_4.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using (var ofDlg = new OpenFileDialog())
{ 
    //скрываем лишние файлы из диалога
    ofDlg.Filter = "Comma Separated Value Files (*.csv)|*.csv";
    ofDlg.CheckFileExists = true;

    if (ofDlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(ofDlg.SelectedPath))
        {
        }
    }
}
```